# check for duplicate objectIds in a list within a list

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, for-loop

i am trying really hard to wrap my head around how to solve this one:
i am currently running through a list of "buildingObjects" that contains a reference, and another list with "assets" which contains a "ObjectId".

```
            var typeBuildingPart = new List<IfcBuildingPart> {
            new IfcBuildingPart{
                BIMId = "iojeofhwofh308ry308hi32r08yrh",
                Reference = "234",
                Assets = new List<IfcAsset> {
                    new IfcAsset{
                        ObjectID = 6111838616,
                    }
                }
            },
                            new IfcBuildingPart{
                Reference = "235",
                Assets = new List<IfcAsset> {
                    new IfcAsset{
                        ObjectID = 6111838616,
                    }
                }
            },
               new IfcBuildingPart{
                Reference = "235",
                Assets = new List<IfcAsset> {
                    new IfcAsset{
                        ObjectID = 6111838616,
                    }
                }
            },
        };
```

The goal is to iterate through the references and the objectId's to check if there is any instance where an objectId might have a different reference (as shown in code snippet, where the objectID of the assets are the same, but they do not have the same reference, and then finally keep the reference that has been refered to the most.
i tried on and of to do multiple for-loops, but end up failing. is there any good linq methods to solve this, or any pointers?
thank you!

there should be more than one assets, but i've only chosen one per buildingpart to demonstrate the ObjectId issue

the final outcome should be that the ifcasset with reference of 234 should be removed.

Comment: Show some of your code. Otherwise, we will have to guess how you tried to implement it or implement it for you, which is not good for your own education. It can either be done with multiple for loops or LINQ, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Is there always only one `IfcAsset` per `IfcBuildingPart`? If so, why have a list of them? If not, what happens if there's more than one?

Comment: _" then finally keep the reference that has been refered to the most"_, May we have an [mcve] with the expected result. In your exemple it's not clear witch Reference  you want as every `IfcBuildingPart` has the same `Assets`.

Comment: there usually is a big list of IfcAssets, with multiple objectId's the code up there is just demonstrative to clarify what i'm trying to do.

Comment: in this example i just want to delete the asset with 234 as a reference

Comment: as for the code i actually havent written anything down yet, i'm not even sure how to attack the issue at all

Comment: @ArnBry, Check my answer. Is it clear? Do you need more information about Any, orderBy or any linq method used? And ultimatly does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if code below helps.  I created two dictionaries which map from object to reference and then reference to object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var typeBuildingPart = new List<IfcBuildingPart> {
                new IfcBuildingPart{
                    BIMId = "iojeofhwofh308ry308hi32r08yrh",
                    Reference = "234",
                    Assets = new List<IfcAsset> {
                        new IfcAsset{
                            ObjectID = 6111838616,
                        }
                    }
                },
                                new IfcBuildingPart{
                    Reference = "235",
                    Assets = new List<IfcAsset> {
                        new IfcAsset{
                            ObjectID = 6111838616,
                        }
                    }
                },
                   new IfcBuildingPart{
                    Reference = "235",
                    Assets = new List<IfcAsset> {
                        new IfcAsset{
                            ObjectID = 6111838616,
                        }
                    }
                }
             };

            var dictRefToObj = typeBuildingPart.GroupBy(x => x.Reference, y => y.Assets.Select(z => z.ObjectID))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.SelectMany(z => z).GroupBy(a => a).Select(a => new { obj = a.Key, count = a.Count()}).ToList());


             var dictObjToRef = dictRefToObj.Select(x => x.Value.Select(y => new { reference = x.Key, obj = y.obj, count = y.count })).SelectMany(z => z)
                .GroupBy(x => x.obj, y => new { reference = y.reference, count = y.count})
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => new { total = y.Select(z => z.count).Sum(), references = y.Select(z => new { reference = z.reference, count = z.count}).ToList()});


        }
    }
    public class IfcBuildingPart
    {
        public string BIMId { get; set; }
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public List<IfcAsset> Assets { get; set; }
    }
    public class IfcAsset
    {
        public long ObjectID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter the list to include only the elment with at least one `IfcAsset` matching your critera. Group on `Reference` and count the number of occurrence. This way you can order by count and take the first .

```
var data = new List<Foo> {
    new Foo{Ref="A", Bars= new List<Bar>{ new Bar {Id="Good" } } },
    new Foo{Ref="B", Bars= new List<Bar>{ new Bar {Id="NotMe" } } },
    new Foo{Ref="C", Bars= new List<Bar>{ new Bar {Id="Good" } } },
    new Foo{Ref="C", Bars= new List<Bar>{ new Bar {Id="Good" } } }
};

var result = data.Where(x => x.Bars.Any(b => b.Id == "Good"))
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Ref)
                 .Select(g => new { count = g.Count(), item=g.First() })
                 .OrderByDescending(x=> x.count)
                 .Select(x=> x.item)
                 .First();
```

Comment: Remove the last first if you need all the `IfcBuildingPart` matching the critera with the most occuring `Reference `.